# What does the anonymous function give me?

Tags: php

I have in tutorial:

```
public function execute(BaseRequest $request)
{
    $operation = function() use($request) {
        return $this->service->execute($request);
    };

    return $this->session->executeAtomically(
        $operation->bindTo($this)
    );
}
```

What does the anonymous function give me?

Why can't I just do:

```
public function execute(BaseRequest $request)
{
    $operation = $this->service->execute($request);

    return $this->session->executeAtomically(
        $operation->bindTo($this)
    );
}
```

?

Comment: @Pierre you should have this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know what framework you're working with here, but my assumption is that `executeAtomically` has some setup and teardown logic included in it, probably starting and committing a database transaction. In such a case, you want the ultimate order of execution of your method to be:

1. Framework setup code is evaluated by `$this->session->executeAtomically()`.
2. Your code (`$this->service->execute($request);`) is evaluated by `$this->session->executeAtomically()`.
3. Framework teardown code is evaluated by `$this->session->executeAtomically()`.

By evaluating the expression yourself rather than wrapping it in a closure, the code instead runs in the following order:

1. Your code is evaluated by your method.
2. Framework setup code is evaluated by `$this->session->executeAtomically()`.
3. Framework teardown code is evaluated by `$this->session->executeAtomically()`.

Most real-world use cases of closures involve some sort of delayed execution, either to perform setup/teardown logic, conduct "lazy loading", execute code multiple times as in a loop, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, it defeats the purpose of anonymous functions however, they're used to extend the functions scope. Since the instance of the `$request` variable isn't being passed through the function, it would be inaccessible without the `use()`. Only anonymous functions allow the `use()` clause to be used, therefore in another context it would be useful if you have global variables which you don't want to continuously pass through a function.

Example:

```
$someDatabase = new PDO();

$doSomeQuery = function( $sql, $bind = [] ) use ( $someDatabase )
{
    $stmt = $someDatabase->Prepare( $sql );
    return $stmt->execute( $bind );
};

// Now we never have to pass the connection in which the developer may not need to know
foreach( $doSomeQuery( 'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col = ?', ['value'] )->fetchAll() as $row ) { ... }
```

Comment: Oh I see. So they can have `$operation->bindTo()` instead of `$operation($request)->bindTo()`. Neat.

Comment: `$operation` is still a closure so it would need to be executed `()` but yes, exactly that. @Anthony

Comment: While technically you could use closures for this, if your primary architectural goal is "I know something you don't know", you would probably be better off making a class and assigning `$someDatabase` as a property of that class.

Answer (score 1):

because when you top function execute is called, it would immediately execute `$this->service->execute($request)` ; the anonymous function seems to be used as a callback which will be later called by `executeAtomically`.

In other words it makes it possible to defer the request (`$this->service->execute($request)`) later, inside `executeAtomically`.